# Load Geoexplorer into Tomcat

Tags: geoexplorer, tomcat

I have installed Tomcat on a Windows server and have successfully deployed Geoserver. I am trying to deploy geoexplorer by building the war file from github and loading it into tomcat to deploy. It loads, but when I go to localhost:8080/geoexplorer, I get a 404 error. How do I load it into tomcat if not that way?

EDIT:
I did load Geoexplorer into the webapps folder of Tomcat and restarted Tomcat.
Here's what is in the log about Geoexplorer:

```
Jul 07, 2014 8:34:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\geoexplorer.war
Jul 07, 2014 8:34:40 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [240] milliseconds.
Jul 07, 2014 8:34:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\geoexplorer.war has finished in 5,844 ms
```

Comment: I'm assuming from what you've posted you've already loaded the war file into your webapps directory.  Does a search of your Tomcat logs (i.e. catalina.out) reveal any failures to properly autodeploy geoexplorer?

Comment: I added some more information to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working on my server now. I have the whole OpenGeo Suite installed on another computer and after looking in the folder for that GeoExplorer, I saw that the classes folder, web.xml and weblogic.xml were missing from the install on Tomcat that wasn't working. I moved those over, restarted tomcat, and went to localhost:8080/geoexplorer/composer/ and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you restart the tomcat service?
According to http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/installation/war/index.html (maybe you installed using application service)
"*Web applications are usually deployed by copying the individual WAR files to an application server’s webapps directory. You may have to restart the container service afterwards. Otherwise, please see your application server’s instructions for further information on deploying web applications.*"
(I dont have enough reputation to comment below author or other post)